# Using variables declared in functions and use them in another function in a different class

Tags: python, wxpython

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MainPanel
import wx

########################################################################
class OtherFrame(wx.Frame):##open PDB frame
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Secondary Frame")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)##create panel

        chain = wx.Button(panel, label = "OK", pos=(100,80),size=(53,25))##button create
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.getchain,chain)##bind event to button go to getchain method


    def getchain(self,event):
    global flag
    flag = 1


import OtherFrame

#######
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):##main frame
    """"""

     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, size = (5000,5000)):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size = (5000,5000))
        self.frame = parent

        Publisher().subscribe(self.showFrame, ("show.mainframe"))

    def showFrame(self, msg):

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
        def createfigure():

       OtherF = OtherFrame.OtherFrame()
       OtherF.getchain()
       print flag
```

First of all I have shortened down my code massively due to it being over 1000 lines of code.
What I am wanting to do is get the variables declared in `getchain` and use them in the `def createfigure`. They are from different classes.
At the moment I am getting the error `getchain() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`
Could someone tell me where I am going wrong, and how to get the variables I use in `def getchain(self,event)` and use them in `def createfigure`

Comment: Your indentation looks like it needs a little help; I would correct it myself but if that is how your original code looks it needs to be corrected there as well.  Additionally, your issue seems to be that you aren't passing `event` to your `OtherF.getchain()` call.  Are you asking how you can get access to that `event`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that. If you really, really want to, then it's better to make the variables class properties by pre-pending them with "self.". So if you want to access the "flag" variable in the other class, make it "self.flag".

Then you can access it using OtherF.flag. However, I think if you need to get something from another class, I recommend using pubsub to pass it around. Here's a tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

When a method is defined as using "self" as a parameter in python, the object it is applied on is implicitly passed as a parameter.  Then, any other parameters you declare must be supplied explicitly in the parentheses.  On the second to last line of the excerpt you provided, you don't supply the required parameter "event".